# How to save/load a Model (Pickle) with a specific path/directory

Tags: machine-learning, pickle

I seems like a very basic think but I couldnt find an answer to it.

I want to save my model to a specific directory using pickle.
The two algorithms below work fine for saving it in the same directory as the code itself but I want to save all my models in a dedicated folder.
I tried to just change the "filename" to "filepath" and well, make it a path but the world isnt that easy it seems.

- Example Path: C:\Learning\Python\Data Science\02_TrainedModels

.

```
# save the model to disk 
filename = 'Father_Son_Height_Model.pckl' 
pickle.dump(lm, open(filename, 'wb'))

filename = 'Father_Son_Height_Model.pckl' 
loaded_model =    pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
```

With This Code:

```
# save the model to disk
filepath = r'H:\99_Lernen\Python\Data Science\02_Trained Models\Father_Son_Height_Model.pckl'
pickle.dump(lm, open(filepath, 'wb'))
```

I get this Error:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'H:\99_Lernen\Python\Data Science\02_Trained Models\Father_Son_Height_Model.pckl'

In this line of code:

```
pickle.dump(lm, open(filepath, 'wb'))
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I edited it in. (a "x" appeard in the path)

Comment: Probably needs to be a raw string literal. Try setting `filepath = r'H:\99_Lernen\Python\Data Science\02_Trained Models\Father_Son_Height_Model.pckl'`. Note the "r" preceding the opening quote.

Comment: Leads to a different error (see question). Intressting detail: In the Console the path is shown with two \\ instead of \ But when I copy it here it is shown with one \. Also the original variable text is with one \. Maybe just strange display from the Console but maybe helpfull.

Comment: Nah that's ok. Regarding the new error...that path definitely does exist, right?

Comment: @Fnguyen is right.. waht a **** error... Thx anyway ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "\" escapes the following sign when parsed, so the path cannot be read.

Use "/" instead and it should work. Also this question was probably more of a SO question ;)

Comment: Yeah probably true, came from a MS problem and thats kinda a follow up, but considering the solution i guess you are right. And Thx off course ^^